# Adding arrows in Tangent

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to add arrows to the start and the  end of the Tangent curve. My first try was successful,

```
Graphics[{First@Plot[Tan[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> {-Pi/2, 
Pi/2}]}, PlotRange -> 8] /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{-0.08, 0.08}], 
Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

but in my next try I get  extraneous gray  arrows over the curve,

```
Graphics[{ First@Plot[Tan[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
Exclusions -> Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi,Pi/2], ExclusionsStyle -> 
Directive[{Gray, Dashed}], Ticks -> {Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/2], 
Automatic}, ImageSize -> 100] /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[0.04], 
Arrow[x]}}]
```

[image]

How I can remove these arrows?

Answer (score 12):

This should do it:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, 
     Exclusions -> Range[-3 π/2, 3 π/2, π], 
     ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed, Arrowheads[{}]], 
     PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04 {-1, 1}], 
     Ticks -> {Range[-2 π, 2 π, π/2], Automatic}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image: tangent function with arrows]

Answer (score 7):

You can also change `Line`s to `Arrow`s using `PlotStyle` as follows:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -2 π, 2 π},
 Exclusions -> Range[-3 π/2, 3 π/2, π], 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], 
 PlotStyle -> ({Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], Arrow @@ #} &),
 Ticks -> {Range[-2 π, 2 π, π/2], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In which version was this capability introduced?